# Row counts from multiple SQL instances/Servers

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, linked-server, rowcount

I have been asked to generate row counts for every table in 4 databases and record the results on a 5th database.

- Database_1 is on Server_a
- Database_2 is on Server_b
- Database_3 is on Server_c
- Database_4 is on Server_d
- Database_5 is on Server_e

The list of tables in each of the databases 1 to 4 are exactly the same.  Occasionally the list of tables will increase/decrease depending on users requirements, but all 4 database will have exactly the same

In Database_5, where the results are needed, they want only one table with the following fields:

```
DateRun (Date row count run), Table_Name, DB1, DB2, DB3, DB4
```

The fields DB1 to DB4 are where the row count results are to be stored.

I am aware of how to link servers and I can use sp_msforeachtable.  But I just cant work out how to get a list of tables from one server into Table_Name, then populate record counts for all 4 databases into fields DB1, DB2, DB3 & DB4

I'm guessing the first query needs to generate a list of tables & row counts from DB1 and insert that into DB5.

Then select row counts from DB2 and update DB5.DB2 where the table names are the same.

Followed by row counts from DB3 and update DB5.DB3 where the table name are the same.

Repeat for DB4.

Or have I got it all wrong.

Would the queries run on DB5 or would I need to run queries on each of the servers and then insert into DB5?  I would prefer to keep everything together on DB5.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sys.partitions` to get a row count. This way you can get all the row counts in one go (without loops, cursors or other flow control logic):

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Results(
    RunId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    DateRun DATE NOT NULL,
    Table_Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    DB1 INT NOT NULL,
    DB2 INT NOT NULL,
    DB3 INT NOT NULL,
    DB4 INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Results(
    DateRun,
    Table_Name,
    DB1,
    DB2,
    DB3,
    DB4
)

SELECT GETDATE()
        ,db1.name
        ,db1.DB1_Rows
        ,db2.DB2_Rows
        ,db3.DB3_Rows
        ,db4.DB4_Rows
FROM (
        SELECT   t.name
                ,p.rows AS DB1_Rows
        FROM DB1.sys.tables t
        INNER JOIN DB1.sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
        INNER JOIN DB1.sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
) db1
    full outer JOIN
        (
            SELECT   t.name
                    ,p.rows AS DB2_Rows
            FROM DB2.sys.tables t
            INNER JOIN DB2.sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
            INNER JOIN DB2.sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
        ) db2
    ON db1.name = db2.name
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT   t.name
                    ,p.rows AS DB3_Rows
            FROM DB3.sys.tables t
            INNER JOIN DB3.sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
            INNER JOIN DB3.sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
        ) db3
    ON db1.name = d3.name
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT   t.name
                    ,p.rows AS DB4_Rows
            FROM DB4.sys.tables t
            INNER JOIN DB4.sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
            INNER JOIN DB4.sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
        ) db4
    ON db1.name = db4.name
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using information schema? This would probably be the best way forward along with some dynamic SQL. There are some good posts about this on the page [DYnamic SQL examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736488/dynamic-sql-examples)